# How to move Linux Swap Partition - GParted

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, swap

I have a dual boot machine with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I want to alocate my space to my home partition but I have to move my Linux Swap Partition.

How can I do it?

Here are my partitions before I shrink C volume in windows:
[Partions before C drive shrink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ptkx.png)

Here it's my partition now with no allocate space: [No allocated partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl5k9.png)

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 is EOL in April of this year time for an upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04. After April no more support for 16.04

Comment: Ubuntu should use every swap partition on the computer. It does not hurt to chane the UUID of the swap partition is /etc/fstab to match the new swap partition.

Comment: Canonical, the maker of Ubuntu will continue to support 14.04 and 16.04 through Extended Security Maintenance until April 2024. Ask Ubuntu is currently trying to change policy to make 16.04 off topic. ESM is free and not too hard to set up. I discus a little bit about activating it at this link: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19510/is-ubuntu-14-04-off-topic-on-ask-ubuntu/19529#19529 You can vote to continue Ask Ubuntu support for ESM versions of Ubuntu here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19543/policy-change-proposal-end-of-standard-support-for-esm-releases-is-effectivel

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use a swap file, remove the swap partition, and reallocate the space. Here’s how you can do it:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Create a swap file of equal (or greater) size to your swap partition:

   ```
   sudo fallocate -l 16G /swapfile
   ```
3. Set the file permissions:

   ```
   sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
   ```
4. Mark the file as a swap location:

   ```
   sudo mkswap /swapfile
   ```
5. Enable the swap file:

   ```
   sudo swapon /swapfile
   ```
6. Update `/etc/fstab` so the changes persist across boots:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/fstab
   ```

   Comment out the current swap partition by adding a `#` to the start of the line. For example:

   ```
   # UUID=abcd1234-1234-abcd-5678-ef0123456789 none   swap    sw      0       0
   ```

   Add the new swap file:

   ```
   /swapfile none swap sw 0 0
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Reboot to test everything is good

So long as it’s all good …

1. Grab a Live USB/DVD and boot into a live session
2. Open GParted
3. Delete the swap partition (as you no longer need it)
4. Resize your main Ubuntu partition by dragging to the left, filling the partition
5. Click “Apply Changes”
   ***Note:** This process may take a long time as data is moved. Do not go this while on battery power.*
6. Reboot

This should result in an additional 60+ GB of storage for your Ubuntu installation